# stretch liquid container along with floated contents

Tags: html, css

basically, i want the `container` to stretch vertically along with the contents inside `id=content`. i cant seem to figure out how, even putting `height:100%` value for the `id=container` doesnt work.

http://jsfiddle.net/hVksr/

CSS for container

```
#container {
width: 400px;
height:100%;
margin:auto;   
background:#ccc; 
}
```

HTML MARKUP

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="head">
       header
   </div>

   <div id="content">
      Contents Here  
   </div>

   <div id="side">
      Side Contents
   </div>

</div>​ <!--/container-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it should work

```
#container {
    width: 400px;
    min-height:100px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:auto;   
    background:#ccc;


}
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: thank you! does putting `min-height` prevents it from having a scrollbar?

Comment: No it wont it is only to make sure after which height the height should be auto