# width:auto and fixed position

Tags: position, width, fixed

I wanted to have menu on top of my website,
but when i set width to "auto" and position to "fixed",
`width:auto;`
made no change in the menu's width and just `position:fixed;` was done.

Answer (score 10):

A bit late to the party on this one, but to get a full width menu, just use

```
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

You can set padding as necessary whilst maintaining a full width bar.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

in your fixed positioned div.
Beware, though, that this solution will not cause the lines to wrap when the div is smaller than the window's width.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want width to be auto try this.

```
width: auto; 
min-width: 100px; 
overflow:hidden;
```

Have a look at my answer in the question

[stretch liquid container along with floated contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206542/stretch-liquid-container-along-with-floated-contents/13206625#13206625)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed  
}
```